# REACT: setState method is not executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I've got a component who is child from another that when is mounted called a function called getData(). This function after make some queries on the databse call to the method setState but this call doesn't work because doesn't change the value of loaded and is no exectuted the callback.

The code of the component is :

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Determinator, MultiLang} from "react-multi-language";
import { getDataFromServer } from "./Functions";
import {GAME_STATS_BY_TEAM, TEAM_COMPETITION_STATS} from "../FEBCOM/Querys";

class TeamTableStandardStats extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.props = props;
        this.state = {
            loaded: false,
            lang: this.props.isFEB ? "es" : "en"
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getData();
    }

    async getData(){
        let params = [
            {"###id_team_club###": this.props.id_team},
            {"###id_competition###": this.props.id_competition}
        ];
        let team_games_stats = {};
        let team_comp_stats = {};
        if (this.props.isFEB){
            team_games_stats = await getDataFromServer(process.env.URL_FEB_API, GAME_STATS_BY_TEAM, params);
            team_comp_stats = await getDataFromServer(process.env.URL_FEB_API, TEAM_COMPETITION_STATS, params);    
        }else{
            team_games_stats = await getDataFromServer(process.env.URL_FIBA_API, GAME_STATS_BY_TEAM, params);
            team_comp_stats = await getDataFromServer(process.env.URL_FIBA_API, TEAM_COMPETITION_STATS, params);
        }
        console.log("getData() => Before setState");
        this.setState = ({
            loaded: true,
            // team_games_stats: team_games_stats.data.game_stats_by_team,
            // team_comp_stats: team_comp_stats.data.team_comp_stats
        }, () => {
            console.log("loaded: " + this.state.loaded);
        });
        console.log("getData() => After setState");
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <span>loaded: {this.state.loaded ? "YES" : "NO"}</span>
                {
                    (this.state.loaded) ?
                        <div>
                            <h1>Tabla - {this.props.isFEB ? "Es FEB" : "Es FIBA"}</h1>
                            <span>id_team: {this.props.id_team} - id_competition: {this.props.id_competition}</span>
                            <span>Resumen: {this.state.team_comp_stats.length}</span>
                        </div>
                        :
                        <h5>
                            <Determinator>
                                {{
                                    es: "Cargando datos ...",
                                    en: "Loading data ..."
                                }}
                            </Determinator>
                        </h5>                     
                }
                <MultiLang lang = {this.state.lang} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

module.exports.TeamTableStandardStats = TeamTableStandardStats;
```

These code when is exected writes in console.log:

[image]

How you can see the log which belongs to this instrucctions is not executed:

```
console.log("loaded: " + this.state.loaded);
```

And how loaded is false you can see this in the view:

[image]

So, I have no idea why is not executing the method setState.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: I know that the change is async but is not called because the callback is not called too. This line is not executed _console.log("loaded: " + this.state.loaded);_

Comment: Yes, I just saw James answer and it looks like a typo in your code prevented the function from being called.

Comment: OMG!!! I have just found my mistake!!! Thank you for your appreciated help!!!

Comment: Glad you found the solution. Consider accepting the right answer, instead of updating your question to include the solution.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro Do it!! ! have remove my solution. Thanks for the message!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't *calling* `setState` at all in your code by the looks of it, you are *setting* it

```
this.setState = ({ ... })
```

This line assigns the value of `setState` which is all wrong, `setState` is a *function* that you need to invoke to update the state i.e.

```
this.setState({
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is a method you should call it instead of assigning a new value to it.

Comment: OMG!!! What a mistake a I have made!!! I found it!!! Thank you so much for your appreciated help!!!